# Should we convert left side operand of xml while comparing?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type has this code:

```
declare @x xml;  
declare @f bit;  

set @x = '<root Somedate = "2002-01-01Z"/>';  
set @f = @x.exist('/root[(@Somedate cast as xs:date?) eq xs:date("2002-01-01Z")]');  

select @f;
```

The above link says

> Instead of cast as xs:date(), you can use the xs:date() constructor function.

So I have formulated it as below, please confirm that above line means the same I have inferred.

That is not using cast as xs:date .

```
declare @x xml;  
declare @f bit;  

set @x = '<root Somedate = "2002-01-01Z"/>';  
set @f = @x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate) eq xs:date("2002-01-01")]');  

select @f;
```

Yours sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I was a bit puzzled about these results...

Obviously within XQuery there is a much closer interpretation of `DATE` and `DATETIME` then I'd expected this. Especially the columns `Equals4` and `Equals5` are never true...

What I've learned is, that one must be extremely carefull, when you want to compare date or dateTime values... Some casts will break, as there is no implicit truncation of a datetime obviously...

Try this:

```
declare @x xml;  

--Somedate1 is your Zone-format
--Somedate2 is a simple ISO8601 date
--Somedate3 is a simple ISO8601 dateTime

set @x = '<root Somedate1 = "2002-01-01Z"
                Somedate2 = "2002-01-01"
                Somedate3 = "2002-01-01T00:00:00"/>';  

--Compare it with a variable with the date as string (try without the "Z" too)
--and a variable with a "real" DATETIME (try with DATE too => Equals9 will not work anymore)
declare @DtAsString VARCHAR(100)='2002-01-01Z';  
declare @DtAsDateTime DATETIME={d'2002-01-01'};  

SELECT
       SimpleData = @x.query('data(/root/@Somedate1)[1]')
      ,DateCtor   = @x.query('xs:date((/root/@Somedate1)[1])')
      ,DtTmCtor   = @x.query('xs:dateTime((/root/@Somedate1)[1])')
      ,CastToDate = @x.query('(/root/@Somedate1)[1] cast as xs:date?')
      ,ToDateTime = @x.query('(/root/@Somedate1)[1] cast as xs:dateTime?')
      ,Val2Date   = @x.value('(/root/@Somedate1)[1]','date')
      ,Val2DtTime = @x.value('(/root/@Somedate1)[1]','datetime')
      ,Equals1    = @x.exist('/root[@Somedate1 eq sql:variable("@DtAsString")]')
      ,Equals2    = @x.exist('/root[(@Somedate1) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,Equals3    = @x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate1) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,Equals4    = @x.exist('/root[xs:dateTime(@Somedate1) eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,Equals5    = @x.exist('/root[@Somedate1 cast as xs:dateTime? eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,Equals6    = @x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate1) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,Equals7    = @x.exist('/root[@Somedate1 cast as xs:date? eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,Equals8    = @x.exist('/root[@Somedate1 cast as xs:date? eq sql:variable("@DtAsString") cast as xs:date?]')
      ,Equals9    = @x.exist('/root[@Somedate1 cast as xs:dateTime? eq sql:variable("@DtAsDateTime") cast as xs:dateTime?]')

UNION ALL SELECT
       @x.query('data(/root/@Somedate2)[1]')
      ,@x.query('xs:date((/root/@Somedate2)[1])')
      ,@x.query('xs:dateTime((/root/@Somedate2)[1])')
      ,@x.query('(/root/@Somedate2)[1] cast as xs:date?')
      ,@x.query('(/root/@Somedate2)[1] cast as xs:dateTime?')
      ,@x.value('(/root/@Somedate2)[1]','date')
      ,@x.value('(/root/@Somedate2)[1]','datetime')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate2 eq sql:variable("@DtAsString")]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[(@Somedate2) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate2) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:dateTime(@Somedate2) eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate2 cast as xs:dateTime? eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate2) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate2 cast as xs:date? eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate2 cast as xs:date? eq sql:variable("@DtAsString") cast as xs:date?]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate2 cast as xs:dateTime? eq sql:variable("@DtAsDateTime") cast as xs:dateTime?]')

UNION ALL SELECT
       @x.query('data(/root/@Somedate3)[1]')
      ,@x.query('xs:date((/root/@Somedate3)[1])')
      ,@x.query('xs:dateTime((/root/@Somedate3)[1])')
      ,@x.query('(/root/@Somedate3)[1] cast as xs:date?')
      ,@x.query('(/root/@Somedate3)[1] cast as xs:dateTime?')
      ,@x.value('(/root/@Somedate3)[1]','date')
      ,@x.value('(/root/@Somedate3)[1]','datetime')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate3 eq sql:variable("@DtAsString")]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[(@Somedate3) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate3) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:dateTime(@Somedate3) eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate3 cast as xs:dateTime? eq xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[xs:date(@Somedate3) eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate3 cast as xs:date? eq xs:date(sql:variable("@DtAsString"))]')

      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate3 cast as xs:date? eq sql:variable("@DtAsString") cast as xs:date?]')
      ,@x.exist('/root[@Somedate3 cast as xs:dateTime? eq sql:variable("@DtAsDateTime") cast as xs:dateTime?]')
```

The result

```
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| SimpleData          | DateCtor    | DtTmCtor            | CastToDate  | ToDateTime          | Val2Date   | Val2DtTime              | Equals1 | Equals2 | Equals3 | Equals4 | Equals5 | Equals6 | Equals7 | Equals8 | Equals9 |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2002-01-01Z         | 2002-01-01Z |                     | 2002-01-01Z |                     | 2002-01-01 | 2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1       | 1       | 1       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 1       | 1       | 0       |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2002-01-01          | 2002-01-01  |                     | 2002-01-01  |                     | 2002-01-01 | 2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0       | 1       | 1       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 1       | 1       | 0       |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2002-01-01T00:00:00 |             | 2002-01-01T00:00:00 |             | 2002-01-01T00:00:00 | 2002-01-01 | 2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```